# Where (or when) should I register a new taxonomy?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, hooks

I'm writing a plugin and my question is:

Which is the most suitable point in which to place the code to register a custom_post_type, or a taxonomy:
    "init action", 
    or "activation_hook" ???

1) init action

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_taxonomy' );
function create_my_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy( . . .);
}
```

2) activation_hook

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_myplugin' );
function activate_myplugin() {
    create_my_taxonomy();
    . . .
}
function create_my_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy( . . .);
}
```

remark

the documentation example as init action, but I suspect that activation_hook is more correct

but perhaps it is indifferent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using activation_hook isn't the best idea. Here's why (let's take a look what Codex says about activation hooks):

> When a plugin is activated, the action 'activate_PLUGINNAME' hook is
>   called. In the name of this hook, PLUGINNAME is replaced with the name
>   of the plugin, including the optional subdirectory. For example, when
>   the plugin is located in wp-content/plugin/sampleplugin/sample.php,
>   then the name of this hook will become
>   'activate_sampleplugin/sample.php'. When the plugin consists of only
>   one file and is (as by default) located at
>   wp-content/plugin/sample.php the name of this hook will be
>   'activate_sample.php'.

*You can read more on the full process flow here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook#Process_Flow*

It means, that **activation hook is run only once** - when the plugin is activated, ergo, during every other request, **when the plugin is already active, your taxonomy won't get registered**, so WordPress won't see/understand it.

And of course you register your taxonomy so it is available during every request, when plugin is active.

So yes - **using `init` action is much better idea**... And [Codex is clearly suggesting that](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Usage):

> Use the init action to call this function. Calling it outside of an
>   action can lead to troubles. See [#15568](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15568) for details.

Comment: Yes, `init` action is called during every request. And that's exactly what you want. Taxonomies are registered only for one (current) request - PHP apps don't store its status between requests.